# how to fix ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have borrowed a project from someone and whenever I try to sync the project with Gradle it shows an error:

> ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory
>   'libs'] on an object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "e.surajsingh.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}
```